# updateOrcreate() record new data when i update existing data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to use method `updateOrcreate()`, when data is an empty new record to the database, but when data is existing is updated data,

1. like image bellow **data is empty I want to record new data to database**

[image: this is data empty, I want to record new data to database]

2. like image bellow **data is existing I want to update existing data and record to database**

[image]

this is my code

```
public function simpanDataUn(Request $request)
{

    $mapel_ujian_id = $request->mapel_ujian_id;
    for($i=0; $i < count($mapel_ujian_id); $i++)
    {
        $arr = NilaiUjianAKhir::updateOrCreate([
            'sekolah_id'              => \Auth::user()->sekolah_id, 
            'siswa_id'                => $request->id,
            'mapel_ujian_id'          => $request->mapel_ujian_id[$i],
            'nilai_standar_daerah'    => $request->nilai_standar_daerah[$i],
            'predikat_standar_daerah' => $request->predikat_standar_daerah[$i],
            'nilai_sekolah'           => $request->nillai_sekolah[$i],
            'predikat_nilai_sekolah'  => $request->predikat_nillai_sekolah[$i],
            'nilai_akhir'             => $request->nilai_akhir[$i],
            'predikat_nilai_akhir'    => $request->predikat_nilai_akhir[$i],
        ],
        [
            'nilai_standar_daerah'    => $request->nilai_standar_daerah[$i],
            'predikat_standar_daerah' => $request->predikat_standar_daerah[$i],
            'nilai_sekolah'           => $request->nillai_sekolah[$i],
            'predikat_nilai_sekolah'  => $request->predikat_nillai_sekolah[$i],
            'nilai_akhir'             => $request->nilai_akhir[$i],
            'predikat_nilai_akhir'    => $request->predikat_nilai_akhir[$i],
        ]);

    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data UN berhasil di input');
}
```

I'm using `updateOrCreate()`method, but when i **UPDATED** existing data, the data 
and even create new data, not **updated** existing data, like image below:

[image]

What part is wrong from my code? how to updated existing data using **updateOrCreate()** method?
please help me, thanks

Comment: the first array passed to `updateOrCreate` are the where conditions to find a record ... the second array is what will be updated if there is a record found ... if nothing is found both arrays are merged together and a new record is created

Comment: give me examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can change your code like this :

```
public function simpanDataUn(Request $request)
{

    $mapel_ujian_id = $request->mapel_ujian_id;
    for($i=0; $i < count($mapel_ujian_id); $i++)
    {
        $arr = NilaiUjianAKhir::updateOrCreate([
            'sekolah_id'              => \Auth::user()->sekolah_id, 
            'siswa_id'                => $request->id,
            'mapel_ujian_id'          => $request->mapel_ujian_id[$i],
        ],
        [
            'nilai_standar_daerah'    => $request->nilai_standar_daerah[$i],
            'predikat_standar_daerah' => $request->predikat_standar_daerah[$i],
            'nilai_sekolah'           => $request->nillai_sekolah[$i],
            'predikat_nilai_sekolah'  => $request->predikat_nillai_sekolah[$i],
            'nilai_akhir'             => $request->nilai_akhir[$i],
            'predikat_nilai_akhir'    => $request->predikat_nilai_akhir[$i],
        ]);

    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data UN berhasil di input');
}
```

Like @lagbox say the first array passed to updateOrCreate are the where conditions to find a record ... if it can't find a record by those conditions it will create a new one. You won't create the new one when there's same `sekolah_id`, `siswa_id` or `mapel_ujian_id` right? Then the other field can be updated

Comment: if i using this code, just nilai_standar_daerah'    => $request->nilai_standar_daerah[$i], is updated, whrn i upated other request is null

Comment: Do you already fill all the columns? the other column must be filled too

Comment: Maybe you did a typo with the 'nilai' in `$request->predikat_nillai_sekolah[$i]`

Comment: name="nilai_standar_daerah[]" (form name)

    'nilai_standar_daerah'    => $request->nilai_standar_daerah[$i],(request controller)

Comment: Yeah you use `nillai` instead of `nilai` there

Comment: YESS, YOU ARE RIGHT !! many typo different from name and controller request, 
I'm sorry I wasn't careful, thanks. now its working